# Django doesn't pull data from fetch()

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch()` to make an ajax call to my server. `request.POST` returns an empty `QueryDict` while `request.body` retuns my actual data. What am I doing wrong?!?

Here's my js code:

```
fetch(url, {
            method: "post",
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(async res => ({
                status: res.status,
                body: await res.json(),
                isOk: res.ok
            }))
```

Answer (score 2):

`request.POST` is for form data. But you're not sending form data; you're sending JSON. So there is no QueryDict, and request.POST correctly remains empty.

Comment: When I use jQuerys `ajax` function it works. How can I do this in plain javascript?

Comment: Do what? You can either stop sending JSON, or get the data from request.body.

Comment: Send data like jQuerys `ajax` method using plain javascript. I'm just converting from jQuery to plain javascript and want to let my server-side code to be the same.

Comment: Well, then remove the Content-Type header and the json.serialize() call

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is covered by [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST): basically the POST *only* contains form data. Files and other non-form data are in the FILE and the body attributes respectively.

Comment: I know that and I'm sending data. For example, I send this: {url: "stackoverflow.com"} (which will get stringified before sending) and when I access it using `request.body`, I get `b'{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}'` but `request.POST` remains as an empty `QueryDict`.

Comment: Checkout the description of the FormData object used as the body at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch. Note that form data does not use JSON as the MIME type. The correct MIME type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'